# How to run a cable raceway by doorway with raised floor?

Tags: conduit, coaxial-cable, cover, cable-management

I need to run a coaxial cable (and one more cable like ethernet) by a doorway. The floor is raised approximately 0.65 inches.

I found D-line raceways, and also the floor raceways that are wide (so people don't trip on it). I'm not sure they will fit well because they are right by a raised floor.
I also found baseboard cord channel which might be better but I'm afraid they are taller than the raised floor.

Picture (only one cable is shown but there will be two running left to right):
[image]

Any experience with this? Any idea what would be the best solution here? Breaking the floor is not an option. It should be something that won't require construction.

Thank you.

Comment: It is often easier to go up one side, across the top, down the other side, and resume. That avoids all tripping potential, but takes more cable. Is that an option for you?

Comment: @DougDeden Technically possible but not wanted. We are looking for a floor based solution.

Comment: I think that you'll have tripping and toe subbing as people are trained throughout life that any floor height transitions will occur at the door rather than some distance away from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to update with an answer: at the end only one cable was necessary, which helps. Solution still applicable if two cables were necessary (as originally stated): a plastic raceway of the right size is best in this case. I checked dimensions of all raceways I could find, and chose the one right the size I needed. That avoid extra wasted space and a tripping hazard. The photo might not tell that, but even with two cables it would not be a problem, it wouldn't be projected too far from the door to be unsafe.

The result is nice:

[image]